# Generating components through iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Something weird is going on:
This is my initial state (a .js file)

```
import moment       from 'moment';

let date = moment();
var previousDate = moment("2015-12-25");

export const projects = [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "metadata": {
          "fields": 
            [{
              "id":     1,
              "order":  1,
              "name":   "Name",
              "value":  "Collection 1"
            },
            {
              "id":     2,
              "order":  2,
              "name":   "Created On", 
              "value":  date
            },
            {
              "id":     3,
              "order":  3,
              "name":   "Last Modified On", 
              "value":  previousDate
            },
            {
              "id":     4,
              "order":  4,
              "name":   "Status", 
              "value":  "Filed"
            }],

          "tags": 
            [{
              "id":     1,
              "order":  1,
              "value":  "tag1"
            },
            {
              "id":     2,
              "order":  2,
              "value":  "tag2"
            },
            {
              "id":     3,
              "order":  3,
              "value":  "tag3"
            },
            {
              "id":     4,
              "order":  4,
              "value":  "tag4"
            }]   
        }
      }
```

This is `ProjectsList.js`:

```
import React          from 'react';
import Project        from './Project';
import { projects }   from 'initialState';

export default (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="projectsList">
      {projects.map(project => (
        <article key={project.id}><Project fields={project.metadata.fields} /></article>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this one's `Project.js`:

```
import React  from 'react';

export default (props) => {
  return(
    <ul className="fields">
      {props.fields.map(field => <li key={field.id}>{field.name}</li>) }
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I am trying to render a bunch of projects in a list, and every project contains a bunch of metadata key-value pairs that it shows.

So basically, the wiring does not matter, it all works fine.
Except for this:

If you look up at the initial state file (first one up there), there is an array of multiple objects in `fields`. Each object shows 4 key-value pairs

- id
- order
- name
- value

Now, in `Project.js`, the line where I go

```
{props.fields.map(field => <li key={field.id}>{field.name}</li>) }
```

looks like I can switch the `{field.name}` for `{field.id}`, to show the id in text. Or I can go `{field.order}`, to display the order.

But weirdly enough, if I want to show the actual value of the field, like so `{field.value}`, it throws.

`invariant.js?4599:38`

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Mon Jun 20 2016 21:40:33 GMT-0400). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `StatelessComponent`.
```

I even went as far (sigh) as changing the string `value` in every `fields` to `val`, juste to make sure `value` wasn't some kind of a reserved word.

Still threw.

Anybody can help me understand what I have done wrong, here?
Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning to variable values to the `value` property in your state file, which are most likely not strings, but objects:

```
export const projects = [{
    "id": 0,
    "metadata": {
      "fields": 
        [
        ...
        {
          "id":     2,
          "order":  2,
          "name":   "Created On", 
          "value":  date                 // one
        },
        {
          "id":     3,
          "order":  3,
          "name":   "Last Modified On", 
          "value":  previousDate         // and another one
        },
        ...
        ]
    ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are absolutely right. I just added quotes around those variables and it didn't throw.

I just edited back my original post to show the actual beginning of the initial state file, which included the declaration of those variables.

So in the first place, I chose to put the data in a .js file so that I may use -momentjs- dynamic functionalities within the object rather than putting everything in a static .json file.

How would you suggest I work it out?

Thanks BTW!

Comment: If you are only going to use the timestamps to print it out, format them into a string in the state file. If not, format it in your `Project.js` file into a string.

Comment: Exactly like this.

Answer (score 1):

If `typeof children` returns `"object"` (and `children` is neither an array, nor a ReactElement), it throws:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/dc6fc8cc0726458a14f0544a30514af208d0098b/src/shared/utils/traverseAllChildren.js#L169

Here's a simplest example to demonstrate this:

```
const IllegalComponent = () => <span>{{}}</span>
```

You are supposed to supply a string (or number) so that React could inline that as the children in `<li>`. Children should be something that's renderable and implements [ReactNode](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/glossary.html#react-nodes).

If the children is an object, React would not know how to render it. You should **explicitly** convert the value to String.

Try this to see if it works:

```
{props.fields.map(field => <li key={field.id}>{field.value.toString()}</li>) }
```

Comment: Yep, this solution works as well.
Have to convert to string either in the data source or in the component itself.  
Thanks!

Comment: The downside of that solution, though, is that, since its an iterator, even if the `value` passed is not a variable (like our `date` here), it has to convert it to string anyway. Even if it is a string in the first place. So not that efficient, finally.

Comment: That's right, if you know your schema upfront, you could preprocess the values. I've updated the answer to include the ReactNode document.